# Auto vs concrete type when iterating over vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, int, auto

The book i am reading offers this example when iterating over a `vector`

```
for (auto &e: v) {
  cout << e << endl;
}
```

Suppose v is declared as `vector<int> v`, in other words, we know that the type of elements inside this collection is `int`.

Is using `auto` in any way better or preferred to?

```
for (int &e: v) {
  cout << e << endl;
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. `auto` is preferred. Because if you change the declaration of`v` from:

```
std::vector<int> v;  //before
```

to this:

```
std::vector<float> v; //after
```

If you use `int &` in the `for`, then you have to change that as well. But with `auto`, no need to change!

In my opinion, working with `auto` is more or less like [programming to interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). So if you do an operation `+=` in the loop, and you don't really care about the type of the loop variable `e` as long as the type supports `+=` operation, then `auto` is the solution:

```
for(auto & e : v)
{
      e += 2;
}
```

In this example, all you care about that the type of `e` supports `+=` with `int` on the right hand side. It will work even for user-defined types, which has defined `operator+=(int)`, or  `operator+=(T)` where `T` is a type which supports implicit conversion from `int` . It is as if you're programming to interface:

```
std::vector<Animal*> animals;
animals.push_back(new Dog());
animals.push_back(new Cat());
animals.push_back(new Horse());

for(size_t i = 0 ; i < animals.size(); ++i)
{
       animals[i]->eat(food); //program to interface
}
```

Of course, you would like to write this loop as:

```
for(Animal * animal : animals)
{
       animal->eat(food); //still program to interface
}
```

Or simply this:

```
for(auto animal : animals)
{
       animal->eat(food); //still program to interface
}
```

It is still [programming to interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

But at the same time, the point in @David's comment is worth noting.

Comment: This can be read both ways, it might be better to get a compilation error saying that an `int&` cannot be set from a `float&` than the compiler silently accepting code that was meant to work with ints... Not saying that it is a better idea to have `int&`, it all depends on what you do in the body of the `for` loop, if it does not depend on the exact type `auto` will be better

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I think what you said is very unusual scenario. Usually, we have to change `int` to `float` in which case `auto` is a better solution.

Comment: Agreed. In most cases `auto&` will do... but I am not yet comfortable with types not being explicit everywhere :) (except when I really don't want to know!)

Comment: I think the case for fundamentals varies greatly than from user-defined types. Fundamentals have this nasty habit of being implicitly converted to others, so David's point is very important here -- you can change the collection type, your loop will still compile, but produce nonsense results.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: If I change the collection type, then `for (int &e: v) ` will **not** compile. Note that it is `int & e`, not just `int e`. However, `for (int e: v)` will compile.

Comment: @Nawaz, indeed, so I guess explicitly typing in many cases still doesn't safe one from implicit conversion. :(

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Please see the edit in my answer. I would like to know your opinion.

Comment: @Nawaz: Besides the syntax errors you mean ;) (The container in the second half of the answer holds `Animal*` but you are accessing it as if it was `Animal`)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Oops. Fixed. (Working in C# currently in office, which influenced the C++ syntax here also).

Comment: Also note, that if you change vector to list or set code with c+0x syntax will work, unless container has begin() and end()

Comment: @galadog: True, but then that has nothing to do with *this* discussion of `auto` vs explicit type.

Answer (score 1):

On your first example, you have less dependency on what the elements of the vector are.

Suppose that in a month, you require that your vector stores larger integers, so you will have to use an `std::vector<int64_t>`, or some other, wider type. Now **all** of the code that iterates over that vector is invalid. You'll have to modify each:

```
for (int &e: v) {}
```

For a:

```
for (int64_t &e: v) {}
```

That is why it's better to just let `auto` deduce the internal type. That way you can modify the type stored in your vector for another, compatible one, and all your code will still work.